# sysuptime in snmp

Tags: snmp

I am trying to send trap messages via SNMP.

The examples on the net mention the setting of 'sysUpTime' value, but they lack in explanations. Which is the role of sysUpTime in this context?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sysUpTime is:

> The time (in hundredths of a second) since the network management portion of the system was last re-initialized.

see this RFC for detailed information: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1907#section-2.1